# Including independent research (no mentor involved), with no publication, on application

Tags: application, independent-researcher

I would like to include the maths research I have done in high school on my college apps. It has been submitted to an AMS journal but, as I am sure you are aware, these journals take awhile to carry out the peer review process.

As such, my research is only on Arxiv as of this time. However, because I am not affiliated with a research institution, I had to go through the (grueling) endorsement process to get it published.

Is there any way I could best support my case that my research is not unverified on my application? Note that this research was independent, and aside from some mentors who do not know me well, I do not have anyone to write a recommendation letter regarding my papers. Also the schools I am applying to do not let me upload any files.

Comment: The lack of mentor/recommendation is a much bigger issue than not being able to put the manuscript on arxiv. Undergrad research admissions committees are not math experts, and wouldn't be able to evaluate a manuscript anyway; you need an expert in the field to tell them how strong your work is.

Comment: What would you suggest then? I do have confidence that my work is original, but as I stated above, my mentors do not know me well and I am not comfortable asking them for a recommendation. Is that the only possible avenue?

Comment: Whoever ended up being your endorser seems like a good choice for someone to at least speak to the fact that your research is original.

Comment: True, but finding someone who will take the time to endorse your paper and who is eligible to is already hard enough (these people are often busy). Putting aside the fact that we have never once met and only emailed two or three times, I am not confident he will have either the time or the will to write a full recommendation letter.

Comment: You might want to say what country the colleges are in, as what you describe would be mostly irrelevant for undergraduate admission in U.S. colleges.

Comment: The colleges are in the U.S. Why do you say this would be irrelevant?

Comment: Unfortunately, undergraduate admissions are off topic. But, I would suggest that your best bet is to get a letter of rec from those mentors. College apps are not read by professors, they are read by advisors and admissions counselors. In my experience, they tend to be liberal arts majors (no judgement, I liked all my advisors, I'm just saying, they aren't likely to understand research level math [neither would I]), with the occasional PhD student. You need one of those mentors to explain what you did, why it was cool, and why it qualifies you for school. I don't know why you would be ...

Comment: ... uncomfortable asking them for a letter.

Comment: *Why do you say this would be irrelevant?* --- It's unlikely anyone reading your application has gone much past the quadratic formula in math, and whatever math they once knew would have been forgotten.

Comment: That would be true for most any scientific achievement in college applications, then. I do not expect them to read my paper of course, this question was solely on verification.

Comment: What you want are people --- your teachers, a guidance counselor, college faculty at a nearby college who know you, etc. --- who can speak about the significance of your scientific achievements, and it's these types of testimonials that the admissions people will be familiar with.

Comment: @TejasRao That is because college applicants with real contributions to science are a vanishingly small percentage of the population, such that the system doesn't need to be set up to support them.

Comment: Admittedly off-topic, but as a tiny bit of advice: any letter writer for you can still mention/acknowledge/praise that you worked on an independent project which is now in submission, and that's fine. Then note it in your letter/materials, you can provide a link to the paper (so they can look if they care), and that's all I can think you can or would need to do to confirm you actually did a thing, and then you can talk about it in some detail in your personal statement (I assume there is one, anyway). But very few of us have any inside knowledge of undergrad admissions, so YMMV.